# Query reads way more data on Postgres 13 than 11

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-11, postgresql-13

I have two servers, one running Postgres 11, the other Postgres 13. Both servers have the same amount of RAM and CPU cores/speeds, and both are configured to these parameters. I have a query which on Postgres 13 is noticeably slower than on Postgres 11 (the difference is only 1 second, but that's a ~40% increase, and this ends up being noticeable in my app which executes the query multiple times).

Here is the query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM orders_view
ORDER BY orderdate DESC, order_id DESC
LIMIT 1000
```

`orders_view` is defined as follows:

```sql
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, d.*
FROM orders a
JOIN customers b USING (customerid)
LEFT JOIN exchange c ON c.currencyid = a.currencyid
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT order_items.order_id,
           sum(order_items.itemprice * order_items.quantity::numeric) AS totalusd
    FROM order_items
    GROUP BY order_items.order_id
) d USING (order_id);
```

Running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on both servers reveals that the culprit is a particular hash join in the query plan that is responsible for the difference, and looking at the buffers, I see that Postgres 13 reads way more data than Postgres 11. Both databases have roughly the same data (one is older than the other, but not by a lot, certainly not nearly enough of a difference for the data to be drastically different). The output of both `EXPLAN` calls is below:

Postgres 11:

```
Limit  (cost=62302.29..62304.79 rows=1000 width=494) (actual time=2584.169..2585.417 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=988575
  ->  Sort  (cost=62302.29..62576.83 rows=109816 width=494) (actual time=2584.167..2584.619 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: a.orderdate DESC, a.order_id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1108kB
        Buffers: shared hit=988575
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2528.32..55183.04 rows=109816 width=494) (actual time=77.678..2423.464 rows=109816 loops=1)
              Inner Unique: true
              Hash Cond: (a.currencyid = c.currencyid)
              Buffers: shared hit=988575
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2527.07..25955.77 rows=109816 width=496) (actual time=77.469..1104.928 rows=109816 loops=1)
                    Inner Unique: true
                    Hash Cond: (a.customerid = b.customerid)
                    Buffers: shared hit=262074
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.71..23141.12 rows=109816 width=476) (actual time=0.030..889.032 rows=109816 loops=1)
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Merge Cond: (a.order_id = order_items.order_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=260903
                          ->  Index Scan using order_id on sales.orders a  (cost=0.29..8126.28 rows=109816 width=444) (actual time=0.011..160.707 rows=109816 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=79805
                          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..12696.26 rows=90846 width=36) (actual time=0.017..540.571 rows=109704 loops=1)
                                Group Key: order_items.order_id
                                Buffers: shared hit=181098
                                ->  Index Scan using qi_order_id on sales.order_items  (cost=0.42..9253.19 rows=230750 width=13) (actual time=0.007..240.223 rows=230750 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=181098
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1773.38..1773.38 rows=60238 width=24) (actual time=77.405..77.406 rows=60238 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3703kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=1171
                          ->  Seq Scan on sales.customers b  (cost=0.00..1773.38 rows=60238 width=24) (actual time=0.008..40.508 rows=60238 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1171
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.11..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=11 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.exchange c  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.005..0.012 rows=11 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning Time: 0.469 ms
Execution Time: 2585.894 ms
```

Postgres 13:

```
Limit  (cost=61262.22..61264.72 rows=1000 width=494) (actual time=3529.979..3531.221 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2312609
  ->  Sort  (cost=61262.22..61535.21 rows=109199 width=494) (actual time=3529.978..3530.442 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Sort Key: a.orderdate DESC, a.order_id DESC
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 1092kB
        Buffers: shared hit=2312609
        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=2498.13..54182.96 rows=109199 width=494) (actual time=73.761..3363.457 rows=109199 loops=1)
              Inner Unique: true
              Hash Cond: (a.currencyid = c.currencyid)
              Buffers: shared hit=2312609
              ->  Hash Join  (cost=2496.89..25119.89 rows=109199 width=496) (actual time=73.582..1063.430 rows=109199 loops=1)
                    Inner Unique: true
                    Hash Cond: (a.customerid = b.customerid)
                    Buffers: shared hit=259701
                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.84..22337.17 rows=109199 width=476) (actual time=0.033..847.858 rows=109199 loops=1)
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Merge Cond: (a.order_id = order_items.order_id)
                          Buffers: shared hit=258557
                          ->  Index Scan using order_id on sales.orders a  (cost=0.42..8109.24 rows=109199 width=444) (actual time=0.007..112.548 rows=109199 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=79053
                          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..12207.54 rows=77662 width=36) (actual time=0.022..520.454 rows=109087 loops=1)
                                Group Key: order_items.order_id
                                Buffers: shared hit=179504
                                ->  Index Scan using qi_order_id on sales.order_items  (cost=0.42..8946.09 rows=229068 width=13) (actual time=0.013..211.722 rows=229068 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=179504
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1744.91..1744.91 rows=60091 width=24) (actual time=73.515..73.517 rows=60091 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3695kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=1144
                          ->  Seq Scan on sales.customers b  (cost=0.00..1744.91 rows=60091 width=24) (actual time=0.005..36.682 rows=60091 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1144
              ->  Hash  (cost=1.11..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.017..0.019 rows=11 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
                    ->  Seq Scan on public.exchange c  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.003..0.010 rows=11 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=16
Planning Time: 0.459 ms
Execution Time: 3531.683 ms
```

We can see that Postgres 11 has only 5.5 GB of shared hits, while Postgres 13 has 16GB of shared hits. I assume this explains the difference in processing time, but leaves me wondering why Postgres 13 is reading so much more data to perform the same query, and what can I do about it?

I tried vacuuming the 13 installation, didn't help at all.

UPDATE:
If I put the ORDER BY into the view itself, then suddenly the performance improves drastically on Postgres 13.

New query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=57978.48..58263.48 rows=1000 width=494) (actual time=1394.780..1513.520 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=388217, temp read=295 written=296
  ->  Result  (cost=57978.48..88008.21 rows=109199 width=494) (actual time=1394.778..1512.617 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=388217, temp read=295 written=296
        ->  Sort  (cost=57978.48..58251.48 rows=109199 width=493) (actual time=1394.549..1395.070 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Sort Key: a.orderdate DESC, a.order_id DESC
              Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 624kB
              Buffers: shared hit=260007, temp read=295 written=296
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=23034.29..34629.78 rows=109199 width=493) (actual time=707.751..1293.404 rows=109199 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: (a.currencyid = c.currencyid)
                    Buffers: shared hit=260007, temp read=295 written=296
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=23033.04..32866.46 rows=109199 width=496) (actual time=707.718..1175.399 rows=109199 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: (a.customerid = b.customerid)
                          Buffers: shared hit=260006, temp read=295 written=296
                          ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=20536.99..30083.75 rows=109199 width=476) (actual time=633.699..977.524 rows=109199 loops=1)
                                Merge Cond: (a.order_id = d.order_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=258862, temp read=295 written=296
                                ->  Index Scan Backward using order_id on orders a  (cost=0.42..8109.24 rows=109199 width=444) (actual time=0.010..98.301 rows=109199 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=79358
                                ->  Sort  (cost=20536.58..20730.73 rows=77662 width=36) (actual time=633.681..692.837 rows=109087 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: d.order_id DESC
                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 2360kB
                                      Buffers: shared hit=179504, temp read=295 written=296
                                      ->  Subquery Scan on d  (cost=0.42..12984.16 rows=77662 width=36) (actual time=0.022..560.083 rows=109087 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=179504
                                            ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.42..12207.54 rows=77662 width=36) (actual time=0.020..469.442 rows=109087 loops=1)
                                                  Group Key: order_items.order_id
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=179504
                                                  ->  Index Scan using qi_order_id on order_items  (cost=0.42..8946.09 rows=229068 width=13) (actual time=0.008..203.632 rows=229068 loops=1)
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=179504
                          ->  Hash  (cost=1744.91..1744.91 rows=60091 width=24) (actual time=73.986..73.988 rows=60091 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 65536  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 3695kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=1144
                                ->  Seq Scan on customers b  (cost=0.00..1744.91 rows=60091 width=24) (actual time=0.007..37.447 rows=60091 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1144
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.11..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.023..0.025 rows=11 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                          Buffers: shared hit=1
                          ->  Seq Scan on exchange c  (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=11 width=7) (actual time=0.008..0.015 rows=11 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=16
Planning Time: 0.444 ms
Execution Time: 1514.405 ms
```

Comment: Weird.  It looks like it is the hash join itself, not its children, which is hitting most of the buffers.  I don't understand why that would be.  Maybe TOAST access?  Can you show the output of `EXPLAIN (VERBOSE)`?